# The text is over the app bar in Scrolling Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I created new Empty activity and added below codes.but the problem is the text still over the app bar.how to solve this issue...or any solution please...I searched StackOverFlow.but I couldn't find any answer.and give me relative solution please..
please see below gif image....
    [image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout     
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  tools:context="com.lars.problem.problem.ScrollingActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
  android:id="@+id/app_bar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_layout">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.lars.problem.problem.ScrollingActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling">

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:text="@string/large_text" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"/>

 </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thank you..

Comment: add this line `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to relative layout..

Comment: Check out [this](http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator) tutorial.